# Angular : Running production app and deploy to Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, deployment, build

I'm intending to deploy my project to **production** within **firebase** :

i've done this :

**1.** Running : `firebase login`

**2.** Running : `firebase init`  ( i set Hoisting project )

**3.** Login to firebase

**4.** Running : `ng build --env=prod`

( since running `ng build --prod` fails throwing this error :

> ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   '/home/firas/Bureau/Miraldev-Angular-test/src'  @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
>   @ multi ./src/main.ts

)

the resulting **dist/** folder contains the **index.html** which is supposed to run locally my app:

**index.html :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MiraldevAngularTest</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyC0m1wWVYokXRUrAQmFKwukdvAw3aowEnY",
      authDomain: "miraldev-test.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://miraldev-test.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "miraldev-test",
      storageBucket: "miraldev-test.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "821288466474"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

but when i run it under chrome it throws errors indicating  the absence of those files : **inline.bundle.js , main.bundle.js , polyfills.bundle.js...** )
even they are all present in the **dist/** folder , but it seems not seeing or running them.

**Snapshot of the console of index.html under chrome :**
[image]

**Any ideas to run my production app ??**

Comment: can you try serving app from http server and not from disk? What is the path in your browser when you open index.html? I would expect same path for `inline.bundle.js` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use script in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "deploy:test": "ng build --prod && firebase deploy --project test"
    "deploy:prod": "ng build --prod && firebase deploy --project prod"
}
```

It builds app (as yours) and uploads to firebase hosting. I have production and staging environments. To setup firebase hosting use `firebase.json` and `firebaserc` configs:

`firebaserc`:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "prod": "myproject-prod",
    "test": "myproject-test"
  }
}
```

`firebase.json`:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        ... various security headers
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

In `database.rules.json` I have my security rules for database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read":true,
    ".write":true
  }
}
```